# how to assign array to array by element without taking individual element?

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment

Namely, why doesn't this work?

```
[a,b]=[1,2];
```

I would expect

```
a=1;
b=2;
```

but it just says 'Too many output arguments.'

Is it the only way that

```
a=somearray(1);
b=somearray(2);
```

to do such assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
[a,b] = deal(1,2)
```